# How do I check if 2 items in an array are the same with overloaded operators

Tags: c#, arrays, operator-overloading

How do I check if there are any duplicates in an array?

```
 public static bool operator ==(SolarPanel s1,SolarPanel s2)
        {
            if (s1.Efficiency == s2.Efficiency && s1.Width == s2.Width && s1.Height == s2.Height) return true;
            return false;
        }
    public static bool operator !=(SolarPanel s1, SolarPanel s2)
        {
            if (!(s1 == s2)) return true;
            return false;
            
        }
```

So I have overloaded the operators in this way. I need to make a static method that takes an array of SolarPanel and checks if there are duplicates. How do I the comparison while using the operators=

Comment: You can use Linq methods like `Distinct` and `GroupBy` but you'd want to also override the `Equals` and `GetHashCode` methods which you likely would want to do anyway if you're overloading the equality operators.  Also consider implementing the `IEquatable<T>` interface as well.

Comment: What if `s1` or `s2` will be equal `null`? Also it's not clear why you want to make a comparison using these operators instead of overriding  `Equals` and `GetHashCode` of your solar panel class

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Distinct operator from LINQ. Is used for removing duplicates elements from the sequence (list, array, ..).

```
string[] employeesNames = { "Asutosh", "Kapil", "Sumit", "Rajat", "Preeti", "Sumit", "Kanupriya", "Kapil" };
 
var distinctEmployees = employeesNames.Distinct();
 
foreach(var name in distinctEmployees)
{
    Console.WriteLine(name);
}
```

Result:
Asutosh
Kapil
Sumit
Rajat
Preeti
Kanupriya

For more information:

https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.distinct?view=net-5.0

Comment: I am sorry my message cut off in the middle dont know why. I need a solution without using Linq.